# poi PropertyTemplate.Extent vs BorderExtent

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm just working with Borders using the POI library (Thank you for the amazing work!) and I've just discovered the PropertyTemplate.  While going through the Quick Guide (https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DrawingBorders) I wrote up the following:

```
propertyTemplate.drawBorders(range, borderType, color, extent);
```

While trying to fill in the extent following the quick-guide, it shows "PropertyTemplate.Extent.ALL" for example as a constant.  When I try to match that, the PropertyTemplate.Extent does not exist.

I tried however with "BorderExtent.ALL" and that works.  Is it just a typo in the quick-guide?

I looked for a way to contact them directly about the quick guide but I didn't want to go through all the mailling list or bug contribution sections just for an update on the website.

Does anyone know:

1. If BorderExtent.ALL (or any of the other constants) is correct or should it be PropertyTemplate.Extent.ALL and I'm doing something wrong?
2. Is there a way to notify the POI team to update the Quick-Guide without disturbing to many people?

Thank you!

Alex

Comment: The answer to your first question is here: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/PropertyTemplate.html#drawBorders(org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress,%20org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle,%20org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderExtent)

Comment: Thanks Axel! So now I just need to find a way to get a hold of the team responsible for updating the Quick-Guide.